# Informing someone that the food they are eating is permissible only b'deved(after the fact)

Tags: kashrut-kosher, bitul-batel-null, shaat-hadechak, love-thy-neighbor

Does one need to inform someone that the food they are about to eat is permissible b'deved(after the fact)?

Example 1: Some milk fell into the chulent and the Rabbi employed batel b'shishim and now the chulent is mutar b'deved.

Example 2: If a caterer was preparing food for a wedding and there was a mess up ,and he asked a Rabbi who permitted the food because it is a case of hefsed m'rubah(great loss) and now the food is allowed b'deved.

In these cases does the baal habais have to inform his guest(s) that the food is in a b'deved state?

Comment: re case 1, i believe the Maharshal maintains that not relying on bitul qualifies as quasi-heretical (daas minus).

Comment: Doesn't it come down to "who's *the Rabbi*"? Because not all people keep the same strictness, for some the food is allowed and for some that might be a real Issur.

Comment: Why do you insist that the food is only permissible b'deved (or B'Di'eved)? It's perfectly Kosher food.